# Creating an ASCII SHA-512 hash in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a C# project where we have a text value that is placed in a SQL Server database table in a nvarchar field. The value is hashed using the code below:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("valuetohash");
byte[] bytes = new SHA512Managed().ComputeHash(data);
String result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

Now I need to duplicate creating that same value using T-SQL.

Can someone tell me how I can do that?

I tried `HASHBYTES ( 'SHA2_512', 'valuetohash' )`

but that lacks the ASCII encoding and produces a different value.

Comment: Just fixed a typo in the title, sorry about that.

Comment: Create a CLR Scalar-Valued function, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131043.aspx)

Answer (score 18):

You need to convert binary data to a Base64 string and you may try using the CONVERT function:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max), HASHBYTES ('SHA2_512', 'valuetohash') ,2)
```

Comment: Thanks Trifon, your answer is quite excellent, however did not solve my problem. The values the software places in the db look like "?m???d????" strings, they are not in base64 format. I'm not sure why. Thanks for this comment anyway.

Comment: In my environment the above command returns this string:
C7458FE820F7567EE61763D6789C1D86E57754F0A51C8CDF4BE08CB17DEB871F396EBFD88F595A8AE7313CEE19FBC67C37AD5DD4500B3DD8523F886BF1DDCCBA

Comment: It is important to note here, that the resulting hash changes depending on whether your input string has the type varchar or nvarchar.